# What is Replace Segue in iOS?

Tags: ios, segue

I know how to do it but i need to know the details, internals. How is it different from modal segue?

> replace segue from code

Comment: The statement is stating that I assume remove segue code by replacing it with something else. There's no segue type such as replace segue !

Comment: I don't think so. Please do some research, there is such thing as replace segue. Check out CS139P course.

Answer (score 7):

The differences is **push segue** needs a `UINavigationController` in order to perform.

A **modal segue**  is not in a navigation stack they can only dismiss themseleves you do not pop view back to the previous controller like you do with a push segue.

<strike>A **replace segue** is only relevant on iPad or iPhone 6+.</strike> You can use **replace segue** to replace the contents of the master or detail pane of a `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: Only iPad? Split ViewControllers are now also available on iPhone